# .load() jquery php General question

Tags: php, jquery

This is a general question, I have two pages, a main and a backgound function one (file.php)

Main page loads file.php passing variables:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var page     = $('#page').attr('value');  
    var user     = $('#user').attr('value');
    $('#DIV').load('file.php?user=' + user + '&page=' + page);
});
```

File.php queries database, inserts variables into more jquery stuff..

echos result...

The result on the main page is the desired one. If I fixe the variables in file.php (and load through browser) the script is fully functionnal and interactive.

My problem is as follows:

The file.php part of the main page is not interacive, i.e. when I click on it nothing happens, yet the 2 work fine idependently, together variables are passed, but the result is static.

My question, is this due to the .load() function? Should I be using $.ajax() type GET ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @David - What is your question?

Comment: Your content is incomprehensible.

Comment: Are you saying that if you configure the variables in PHP, it works, but it doesn't work when you use the posted variables? It might help to see your PHP code that grabs the input.

Comment: sorry having connection problems only half of my question was edited. Hope it is more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have jQuery behaviours attached to the DOM that are not being applied to the new content. This is because the new content is loaded after the DOM is ready (ie, after the load event fires).

This can be solved by using the [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) jQuery function to attach events to a selector that will be applied to all elements, regardless of when they're added. E.g, instead of:

```
$('#button').click(function() { alert('hi'); });
```

Use:

```
$('#button').live('click', function() { alert('hi'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is #DIV referring to:

```
<div id="DIV"></div>
```

Perhaps you should try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var page     = $('#page').attr('value');  
  var user     = $('#user').attr('value');

  // see the DIV below with the ID = "myId"
  $("#myId").load("file.php?user=' + user + '&page=' + page", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
      var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
      $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
  });

});  


  <!-- empty containers with ID attributes -->
  <div id="myId"></div>
  <div id="error"></div>
```

If there is an error in the returned data, this will also tell you what the error is.  Also, what does your debugger tell you?

Comment: sorry having connection problems only half of my question was edited.